# Entity Framework Model First Database with inheritance strange bug

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, ef-model-first

I am learning EF and Model First approach. I had created a test app and all works, but with strange bug. I have a table, which has inheritance.

Here it is my EDM scheme: http://gyazo.com/fbec21b5fbfc47dd76ff3eaa38f86d36.png

Also i had a three rows in my Person and Employee tables.
And this is how i select Data from the employee table:

```
private static void GetEmployees()
    {
        using (EmployeesModelContainer context = new EmployeesModelContainer())
        {
            int rowNumber = 0;

            var selectEmployeesQuery = from employee in context.Persons.OfType<Employee>()
                                       select employee;

            foreach (var employee in selectEmployeesQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1} {2} ({3} лет, {4}, {5} образование) - {6}.", ++rowNumber, employee.Name, employee.Surname, employee.Age, (employee.Sex == Sex.Man) ? "Муж" : "Жен", employee.EducationLevel.Level, employee.Profession.NameOfProfession);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here it is what output i have: http://gyazo.com/f2b5f9f052f2a352b6d7ef01a20904f2.png
You can see that after third row i have an empty row! I broke my head from where it is adding!

If i change my SelectQuery like this all will be allright.

```
var selectEmployeesQuery = from employee in context.Persons
                           select employee;
```

**P/S.** I am not sure about my other queries, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. Am i right?

```
private static void AddNewEmployee()
    {
        using (EmployeesModelContainer context = new EmployeesModelContainer())
        {
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee
            {
                Name = "Вася",
                Surname = "Пупкин",
                Age = 34,
                Sex = Sex.Man,
                ProfessionId = 4,
                EducationLevelId = 1
            };

            context.Persons.Add(newEmployee);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void UpdateEmployee()
    {
        using (EmployeesModelContainer context = new EmployeesModelContainer())
        {
            var updateEmployeeQuery = (from employee in context.Persons.OfType<Employee>()
                                       where employee.Name == "Вася"
                                       select employee).FirstOrDefault();

            updateEmployeeQuery.Age = 39;
            updateEmployeeQuery.EducationLevelId = 2;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void DeleteEmployee()
    {
        using (EmployeesModelContainer context = new EmployeesModelContainer())
        {
            var deleteEmployeeQuery = (from employee in context.Persons.OfType<Employee>()
                                       where employee.Name == "Вася"
                                       select employee).FirstOrDefault();

            context.Persons.Remove(deleteEmployeeQuery);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The question is, If I need to **add** or **delete** some data in **Employees** table, why i am adding or deleting in **Person** table and it is allright? Data adding in **Person** and in **Employees** tables.
And if I **Updating** some data in **Employees** table, why the data is updating in **Person** table correctly?

Comment: this might be just some autowrapping "error". try changing your console resolutions (make it a bit wider)

Comment: damn yes!!!!!!!!!!! aaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrr